# Google Cast SDK for iOS crash with DCIntrospect

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, google-cast

On my app, when I add the googleCast SDK, the app crash at launching, on this method `[[DCIntrospect sharedIntrospector] start];`. But when I don't have GoogleCast SDK, everything is working fine.

Here is the assertion log :

`*** Assertion failure in -[GCKPB_PBFieldDescriptor initWithFieldDescription:rootClass:], /Volumes/BuildData/pulse-data/agents/wpye22.hot/recipes/415961027/base/googlemac/iPhone/Chromecast/SDKv2/Protos/../../../../ThirdParty/ProtocolBuffers/objectivec/Classes/PBDescriptor.m:409
This works fine if I run the project on an iPhone 5C, but crashing on the simulator (32-bit simulator).`

Any idea on how to solve this crash, and still continue to use `DCIntrospect` ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I was able to reproduce this issue, so I filed [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=205).

Introspection triggers the +initialize method of the GCKPB_PBGeneratedMessage class.
This method apparently makes some bad assumptions about when +initialize will get triggered.

Answer (score 0):

While waiting for a fix you can always use the workaround suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22537926/1952815) and mock `GCKPB_PBGeneratedMessage`'s `+initialize` method.